# about running rosjava on android emulator

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

I would like to ask a general question. Right now, i am trying to test ros android examples on android emulator. I would like to know how well android emulator support those examples? Do i need a real android phone to test those examples?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34288/about-running-rosjava-on-android-emulator/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not recommend developing against the emulator.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0